# Displaying Category Image in navigation menu in magento

Tags: magento

I am new to magento and i need a little help in displaying the image from the category,
i have uploaded a image in category from my magento backend, and i am trying to display in the navigation bar like this

```
<ul id="nav_category" class="nav_category">  
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
    <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?> 
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())-     >getImageUrl()    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

But its not displaying the image url, it just displays the name of the category from the drawItem function.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vikash,try the below code....

```
  <ul id="nav_category" class="nav_category">  
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
        <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?> 
    <?php
        $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        $_imgHtml   = '';
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
            $_imgHtml = '<img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$_category->getName().'" />';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }
    ?>
    <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
        <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display category images in top navigation menu in magento1.9: 
Steps:

1. Load category object:

   ```
   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('category-id');
   ```
2. Then call `getData()` method:

   ```
   $category->getData('image');  // It will return image url;
   ```
3. Then add media directory path:

   ```
   Mage::getBaseUrl('media'); // returns megento media directory path.
   ```

Below is sample code that i have used.

```
$splittedArray = explode($delimiter = 'category-node-', $child->getId());
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(end($splittedArray));

if (!empty($category->getData('image'))) {
    $html .= '<div> ';
    $html .= "<a href=" . $category->getURL() . " title =" . $category->getName() . ">";
    $html .= "<img src=" . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/category/' . $category->getData('image') . " alt=" . $category->getName() . " >";
    $html .= "</a>";
    $html .= '</div>';
}
```